# Show that $[(x,y,z)] = \dfrac{xy + xz + yz}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ is smooth.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

This is a function from the real projective space $f: RP^2 \to R$. I need show $f \in C^{\infty}$.

Again,

$[(x,y,z)] = \dfrac{xy+xz+yz}{x^2 +y^2 + z^2}$

I think it's pretty simple, but I need show that $all$ derivatives exists, including mixed, right? 
Is there an easy way to do this? I obviously can't take infinintely many derivatives, so I need some sort of shortcut. Any tips would be fantastic. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ is well defined on $RP^2$.

The three functions
$$\phi:\quad{\mathbb R}^2\to RP^2,\qquad(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,1)/_\sim$$
and similarly $\psi$ and $\chi$ form an atlas on $RP^2$. Expressing $f$ in terms of $\phi$ we obtain
$$\tilde f(x,y)=[(x,y,1)]={xy+x+y\over 1+x^2+y^2}$$
which is obviously $\in C^\infty({\mathbb R}^2)$.